# Google App Engine update only one property of an entity that has many efficiently java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Looking for an efficient way to update only one property for an entity in GAE.
I know I can do a get by key, set a property and then put.  But will the get not be very inefficient as it will load all properties?  I have heard that you can make property specific queries but I was worried that once you load an entity with only say one or two out of its total properties, then put it back in the datastore that the properties not loaded in the query will be lost.

Any Advice?

PS also not sure about the query method because I heard direct gets are more efficient.  Any possibility of a query that specifies simply the key and therefore will be just as efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik, entities are stored in a serialised form, so it makes no difference if you need one or all properties as they will all be loaded when entity's serialised form is loaded.

The "property specific queries" are actually called [projection queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries). They work on indexes only and only recreate "projected" fields you queried by. Since entities are only partially loaded (only projected fields are loaded) they [**should not be saved back to the Datastore.**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries#Java_Limitations_on_projections)

Just use normal query and then multi-put. Yes, direct gets are more efficient (and less costly) but you need to have key/id of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update one property far more than others, you can move it into a separate, simpler entity that you can load and update independently of the main entity. This could be a child entity, or a separate one that shares key characteristics.

E.g.

- Email <- main entity
- Unread <- child entity of email

When the email is created, create an unread entity. When it's read, delete the unread entity. When searching for unread emails, perform a key-only query on the Unread entities, extract parent keys to find the Email entities you want.